# Java exception in Mathematica while trying to access MS Access

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to make "Wolfram Mathematica" to manipulate a *.accdb file. I already established a connection (to a file with an empty "table1"):

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection[]
```

Source: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLInsert.html

It works fine. If I make:

```
SQLSelect[conn, "table1"]
```

I get

```
 {}
```

Now I want to create a table with:

```
SQLCreateTable[conn, 
  SQLTable["TEST"], {SQLColumn["COL1", "DataTypeName" -> "INTEGER"], 
   SQLColumn["COL2", "DataTypeName" -> "DOUBLE"]}];
```

I get the exception:

> Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.clearParameters(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:214)
>     at
>   com.wolfram.databaselink.SQLStatementProcessor.processSQLStatement(SQLStatementProcessor.java:311).

Sorry for bad english (but I tried).

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes if you "open the same connection" many times Mathematica doesn't understand what to do. Just

```
Quit
```

the Kernel and re-establish the connection. SQL will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a database, e.g.

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection["demo"]
```

Comment: No.... That opens the connection to the "demo" Database. OpenSQLConnection[] opens a GUI, with that GUI you can open a connection manually....